# iptables: block incoming but allow outgoing

Tags: block, iptables

I use an ubuntu server to power my home network. the server is **directly connected to the internet** via the interface **wan0**. on the **intranet** site it uses a bridge **br0** (which joins lan0 and wlan0).

to block incoming requests from the internet i use **iptables**. it **works** fine **to block incoming requests**, but i have the issue, that **the server itself** (not the clients of the intranet) is **no longer able to connect to the internet** (e.g. with ping 9.9.9.9).

the used iptable rules look like the following:

```
*filter
# Global policies (drop the whole input)
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [12:948]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [52:5479]

# Allow loopback for device local communication
--append INPUT --in-interface lo --jump ACCEPT

# Allow all input from the intranet
--append INPUT --in-interface br0 --jump ACCEPT

# Allow ssh on port 22 from the wan
--append INPUT --in-interface wan0 --protocol tcp --dport 22 --match conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED --jump ACCEPT

# Allow ping from the wan
--append INPUT --in-interface wan0 --protocol icmp --icmp-type echo-request --jump ACCEPT
COMMIT

*nat
# Global policies
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [362:62516]
:INPUT ACCEPT [57:12612]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [43:4250]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [31:2839]

# NAT traffic to the wan
--append POSTROUTING --out-interface wan0 --jump MASQUERADE

COMMIT
```

can somebody please help me find the issue or which rule i do have to add, so the servers requests are able to get into the internet again?